# Can MySQL link (mysql_connect) be stored in Memcache and reused?

Tags: php, mysql, memcached

In PHP, can I do this?

```
$mysql = mysql_connect(...);
Memcache::set('mysql_connection', $mysql);
```

and then in another script

```
$mysql = Memcache::get('mysql_connection');
mysql_query("some query", $mysql);
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, but you can use a pool of permanent connections with `mysql_pconnect()`.

Answer (score 1):

No, it can't. `$mysql` is actually just a memory pointer to the real MySQL link. The MySQL link is destroyed at the end of the script whether you want it or not, and you are left with a pointer to an undefined place in memory.